# Simple drawing with mouse on cocoa swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I can't find any simple solution to draw on view with mouse. All [tutorials](http://www.knowstack.com/drawing-in-swift-cocoa/) using `NSBezierPath` to draw lines, rects etc. But I need a simple app drawing with mouse like this: http://juliuspaintings.co.uk/cgi-bin/paint_css/animatedPaint/010-NSView.pl

I tried to convert it. But nothing works for me:

```
var lastPoint = NSZeroPoint
    var red: CGFloat = 0.0
    var green: CGFloat = 0.0
    var blue: CGFloat = 0.0
    var brushWidth: CGFloat = 10.0
    var opacity: CGFloat = 1.0
    var swiped = false

override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
        if !swiped {
            drawLineFrom(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: lastPoint)
        }

    }

    override func mouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {
        swiped = true
        let currentPoint = event.locationInWindow
        drawLineFrom(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: currentPoint)
        lastPoint = currentPoint
    }


    func drawLineFrom(fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint) {
        print("drag")
        var ctx = NSGraphicsContext.current
        ctx?.cgContext.setStrokeColor(CGColor(red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0))
        ctx?.cgContext.setLineWidth(5.0)
        ctx?.cgContext.beginPath()
        ctx?.cgContext.move(to: fromPoint)
        ctx?.cgContext.addLine(to: toPoint)
        ctx?.cgContext.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)
        ctx?.cgContext.closePath()
    }
```

Please suggest how can i draw single point

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I created a simple demo which can draw something with mouse event. You can change the any parameters if you want like color or line width etc.

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    let view = DrawView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.window.contentView?.addSubview(view)

    self.window.contentView?.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[view]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["view": view]))
    self.window.contentView?.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[view]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["view": view]))
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

}

class DrawView: NSView {
var path: NSBezierPath = NSBezierPath()

override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    path.move(to: convert(event.locationInWindow, from: nil))
    needsDisplay = true
}

override func mouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {
    path.line(to: convert(event.locationInWindow, from: nil))
    needsDisplay = true
}

override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.draw(dirtyRect)

    NSColor.black.set()

    path.lineJoinStyle = .roundLineJoinStyle
    path.lineCapStyle = .roundLineCapStyle
    path.lineWidth = 10.0
    path.stroke()
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: awesome thanks, but could you answer, why on obj - c all examples use NSGraphicsContext and on IOS UIGraphicsContext, but in cocoa you use `NSBezierPath`

Comment: @Arti For your requirements, there are many ways to do so, I just pick the easiest way to do the job :] Please check what is difference between different technology: https://www.evanmiller.org/notes-on-2d-graphics-mac.html

Comment: `NSBezierPath` is a different abstraction over "point to point drawing". You can use `NSGraphicsContext` to draw a `CGMutablePath`, too, but the API is very old and, let's say, feels like writing C code.